# Getting difference of dates based on minutes and seconds

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two date columns, the first one is for beginning, the second one is for ending.

[image: Two of our columns]

We want to get difference of these dates based on minutes and seconds. My Goal is get result as below:

***1:05:06(1 min 5 seconds)***

I have tried functions such as `date_trunc(), datediff()` and `EXTRACT(EPOCH))` but we couldn't do that. Can you please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method is `-`:

```
select (end_ts - start_ts) as diff_time
```

If you want this in seconds, you can convert to epoch time and subtract:

```
select extract(epoch from end_ts) - extract(epoch from start_ts) as diff_seconds
```

Comment: I want both of them, minutes and seconds.

Comment: @berkayln . . . The first solution should do what you want.